# WD external HD no working

Tags: external-hdd

I have a password protection on my external HDD and in windows I'm always prompted to input the password when I connect my external HDD to it. But in Ubuntu it mounts fine but it does not request me to input a password and I dont have access to any of my files on the external HDD please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are more than likely using the password protection feature of the Western Digital bloatware that came on the drive, correct? If that is the case I would recommend removing the password from the disk using the Windows software, at which point you would be able to mount it properly under Linux. I'll continue researching the topic to see if I can find a work-around for you, but I really doubt it as it's more than likely propriety WD code to enable the feature.

[Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/why-doesn%27t-westren-digital-support-linux-for-the-external-drives-890050/)

[Source 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1284828)